# How can I make pgfplots table recognize fractions?

Tags: pgfplots

Is there any way to make pgfplots automatically convert fractions in a table to a floating point number for plotting as in the following example?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table[col sep=&,row sep=\\] {
      1 & 1/4 \\
      2 & 3/5 \\
      4 & 7/8
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way, is to give your columns names (e.g `x` and `y`) and then to use

```
y expr={\thisrow{y}}
```

as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table[col sep=&,row sep=\\,y expr={\thisrow{y}}] {
      x & y \\
      1 & 1/4 \\
      2 & 3/5 \\
      4 & 7/8 \\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively (thanks to [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t)), if you'd prefer not to name your columns, you could use

```
\addplot table[header=false,col sep=&,row sep=\\,y expr={\thisrowno{1}}
```

as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table[header=false,col sep=&,row sep=\\,y expr={\thisrowno{1}}] {
      1 & 1/4 \\
      2 & 3/5 \\
      4 & 7/8 \\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thisrowno{1}` will give the value in the second column, so naming isn't strictly necessary. (+1 though).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. many thanks :) I had considered this previously, and I'm glad you high lighted this. I've incorporated it.